# How to compare two Hashtables?

Tags: c#

I am developing a small RTS in XNA.

I'm setting each unit "goto" position as the vector they should go to. Everything works fine if I don't compare the two Hashtables, but when I do, I get this "NullReferenceException was unhandled" annoying error.

Here's the piece of code:

```
if (((float)unit[(int)selectedunits[I+"ID"] + "posX"] != (float)cgoto[(int)selectedunits[I+"ID"] + "X"]) && ((float)unit[(int)selectedunits[I+"ID"] + "posY"] != (float)cgoto[(int)selectedunits[I+"ID"] + "Y"]))
```

Comment: And you should learn to write cleaner code...

Answer (score 3):

1. the NullReferenceExceptions are happening when you cast `null` (from a missing entry in some hash table) to an `int` or `float`. Without knowing your code, I'd hazard a guess that there is no entry in `cgoto` for the selected unit.
2. Learn to do things in the proper object-oriented way. the code should really look something like

   ```
   if (selectedUnits[i].pos != selectedUnits[i].gotoPos)
   ```